# Wordpress tag filtered drop down form for wordpress pages

Tags: php, jquery, html, wordpress

I'm working on a site for a client, who has specified he wants to replicate the functionality of the Rehab center database drop-down form on WordPress located at http://brainandspinalcord.org/ for a section on his own site.

I would like to modify the contents to be filtered by a tag assigned to a page, so that adding to the list is a simple matter of assigning that tag to a page; A plugin solution is preferred, but rather difficult to find, as the word drop-down is used generally for header menus that expand on hover to show sub-pages.

Instead, after researching, I found this code:

```
<li id="pages">
<h2><?php _e('pages:'); ?></h2>
<form action="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>" method="get">
<?php wp_dropdown_pages(); ?>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="view" />
</form>
</li>
```

How can I add a tag based filter to this?

Comment: you want a dropdown of all tags?

Comment: It is a drop down of pages, with a tag assigned to them so that the only pages in the form are pages with that tag.

Answer (score 0):

Further research into the subject turned up [Documentation on the function](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dropdown_pages) which I found an argument for child_of that will generate the desired functionality.